# FedEx RESTful APIs patch for Magento ver. 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4

Getting email from FedEx

Magento ver. 2.3.4

Please be reminded that on and from 15 May 2024 our support for your connection with FedEx Web Services will end and be replaced by the new FedEx RESTful APIs. Our technical team will no longer be available to support FedEx Web Services from that day forward.

Let me know how update it , or available patch for it ?FedEx RESTful APIs simplify system integration, improve security, and elevate the customer experience. We are developing additional features, and all new enhancements will only be available in FedEx RESTful APIs. Get ready to serve your customers with greater ease, flexibility, and agility by upgrading your system now!

Let me know how update it , or available patch for it ?